# program crashes when trying to access clipboard

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to get clipboard data via QClipboard. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::getText()
{
    QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
    const QMimeData *mime = clipboard->mimeData (QClipboard::Selection);
    QString originalText = clipboard->text(); // no crashes in windows
    //QString originalText = mime->text (); //this line causing program crash
    .................
}
```

`getText()` called every 5 second using QTimer. The above code works perfectly in linux, when I try to run the code in windows 7 it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't support `QClipboard::Selection`, that's why application crashes everytime. Here is how I solved it

```
QString originalText;
if(QSysInfo::productType() == "windows") {
            QString clipboard = QApplication::clipboard()->text();
            originalText = clipboard;
    } else {
      // for linux
        QClipboard *clipboard = QGuiApplication::clipboard();
        const QMimeData *mime = clipboard->mimeData (QClipboard::Selection);
        originalText = mime->text ();
    }
```

Comment: Note that macOS also does not support this feature, so your code will fail in this case. It's better to use [`QClipboard::supportsSelection()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html#supportsSelection) for this check, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

`clipboard->mimeData` can be null, so you might want to either cache the previous state, or do the following:

```
QString originalText = mime ? mime->text() : QString();
```